# Inside of a lamba expression trying to divide two values and compare to another value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

C# - Inside of a lambda expression trying to divide two values and compare to another value, after checking that they are not equal to null. Doesn't seem to work in lambda expression but works in (what I think ) is equivalent foreach expression. By work I mean  none of the test data satisfies the expression; the behavior of foreach code represents this (value of found after foreach code executes remains false, however, the list in the lambda expression will contain elements after code executes). I am kinda new to lambda and linq expressions, what is going on here?

linq expression is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<DataModel> list = dataList.Where(t => t.A != null 
         && t.B != null 
         && t.Compute1.Value.CompareTo((t.B.Value / t.A.Value)) != 0);
```

This does work in following foreach statement:

```
var found = false;
foreach (var data in dataList)
{
    if (data.A == null || data.B == null )
    {
        continue;
    }
    var value = (double)data.B.Value / data.A.Value;
    if (data.Compute1.Value.CompareTo(value) != 0)
    {
        found = true;
    }
}
```

**Update:** I fixed this issue by casting t.Compute1, t.A, and t.B to double even though VS tells me cast is redundant.

Comment: Almost certainly the fact that you cast `(double)data.B.Value` in the loop and not the lambda.

Comment: I believe I tried casting as well in the lambda

Comment: --the list in the lambda expression will contain elements after code "executes"-- which one ? list or dataList ?

Comment: list contains elements

Comment: Are you looking for a specific elements (suggested by linq) or trying to determine if any of the elements in the sequence fits the comparison?

Comment: SORRY looks like haney is right. Just tried casting again in lambda expression and now i'm getting expected behavior. thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @Gerino the question is why does he get 2 different results. However, for me just the double cast is different in your code. Are your sure using the same test data ?

Comment: simple mathematics... If B/A == 0, that means that B == 0... Why are you losing time trying to achieve useless checks?

Comment: Please don't vote down my question.  I don't think you understand my question. No where am I testing to see if b/a is equal to zero. In testing value of b/a against a different value called compute 1. These values are properties in my data model

Comment: There are no useless checks or redundant checks in this code

Comment: Code checks if both a and b are not null (they are nullable ints). If both not null,  compares to value of Compute1 (which is a nullable double). What's redundant about that?

Comment: this question should never have been down voted

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe actually in first part of expression I'm making sure values arent null then I'm doing the math against the values. There are no useless checks here. Please don't down vote this.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not equivalent pieces of code.  Your foreach loop stops searching the moment it finds a data element where either A or B is null.  Your lambda checks all the elements even if a previous one had A == null or B == null.  The closest foreach equivalent would be to replace the break with a continue.

```
var found = false;
foreach (var data in dataList)
{
    if (data.A == null || data.B == null )
    {
        continue;
    }
    var value = (double)data.B.Value / data.A.Value;
    if (data.Compute1.Value.CompareTo(value) != 0)
    {
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good point about continue. I was incorrectly using break. However, with this test data, none of the data is null.